# Conflict of OneSignal Unity SDK with Google Play Games Plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, onesignal

I am trying to integrate OneSignal 2.4.1 Unity SDK in my project that already implements the Google Play Game Services for Unity (version 0.9.42)

Using only the Google Play Games plugin i can normally login to the services in my android game. When i integrate OneSignal my app crashes when i try to login.

Keep in mind that when i import OneSignal SDK i get the following Warning message  in Unity console:

> Found conflicting Android library gpgs-plugin-support
>
> Assets/Plugins/Android/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42 (managed by the
>   Android Resolver) conflicts with:
>   Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.9.42/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42.aar
>
> Your application is unlikely to build in the current state.
>
> To resolve this problem you can try one of the following:
>
> - Updating the dependencies managed by the Android Resolver to remove
>     references to old libraries. Be careful to not include conflicting
>     versions of Google Play services.
> - Contacting the plugin vendor(s) with
>     conflicting dependencies and asking them to update their plugin.
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object) 
>   Google.Logger:Log(String,LogLevel)GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String,
>   LogLevel) GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:FindAndResolveConflicts()
>   GooglePlayServices.c__AnonStorey17:<>m__29()
>   GooglePlayServices.c__AnonStorey18:<>m__26(List`1)
>   GooglePlayServices.c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
>   GooglePlayServices.c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
>   GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

I used the Android Resolver (both the 'Resolve' and 'Force Resolve' options) but still my app crashes when i try to log-in to google play services.

Any ideas on how to fix the above issue?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any code or error log?

Comment: delete Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.9.42/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42.aar

Comment: @Gonzalo 

Well I get the above message as a warning in Unity console.

The interesting part is when I connect my mobile phone to the computer and deploy a Development Build with Script Debugging it works! Thus I don’t get an error message. This only happens in my phone, but when I try the particular apk in an emulator (KOPLAYER or MEmu) it crashes.

In a release build it crashes even on my device.

Turnipinrut I tried that and I still get a crash.